# Инициализация БД MSSQL в DOCKER

Tags: sql-server, docker

Подскажите как инициировать БД после запуска docker mssql

DOCKER-COMPOSE:

```
version: "3.2"
services:

  test-database:
    build: ./mssql_database
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    environment:
        SA_PASSWORD: "Super_puper_password"
        ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
        TZ: "UTC"
```

DOCKERFILE:

```
FROM microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest
COPY setup.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

БД поднимается, но setup.sql не запускается

Comment: Сделайте это как в документации



MYSQL_DATABASE

This variable is optional and allows you to specify the name of a database to be created on image startup. If a user/password was supplied (see below) then that user will be granted superuser access (corresponding to GRANT ALL) to this database.

https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql

Comment: @zalex вопрос про Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался как это все дело запустить. Оставлю тут для потомков.

dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest

COPY setup.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
COPY entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
COPY import-data.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

#CMD /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P Super_puper_password -d master -i /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/setup.sql

#Ставим обновления и меняем формат файлов на тип юникса если будут ошибки в файлах типа \r
#RUN apt-get -y update  && \
#    apt-get install -y dos2unix
#RUN dos2unix /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/entrypoint.sh
#RUN dos2unix /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/import-data.sh

#Даем права на энтрипоинт
RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/entrypoint.sh

#Говорим докеру запустить наш энтрипоинт
ENTRYPOINT /bin/bash /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/entrypoint.sh
```

docker-compose

```
version: "3.2"
services:

  test-database:
    build: ./mssql_database
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    environment:
        SA_PASSWORD: "Super_puper_password"
        ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
        TZ: "UTC"
```

entrypoint:

```
/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/import-data.sh & /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
```

import-data.sh

```
echo "Sleeping 90 sec" && sleep 90s && echo /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P Super_puper_password -d master -i /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/setup.sql && /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P Super_puper_password -d master -i /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/setup.sql && echo "setup.sql completed"
```